# How do I select the shadow DOM host element only if it is the last-child?

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-element

I am looking to select the shadow DOM host element only if it is the last child.

In this example they are all green, I want them to be all red except the last one.

```js
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <h5>Element:</h5>
      <slot></slot>
      <style>
        :host {
          color: red;
        }
        :host-context(:last-child) {
          color: green;
        }
      </style>
     `;
  }
}
window.customElements.define('my-custom-element', MyCustomElement);
```

```html
<div>
  <my-custom-element>first</my-cutom-element>
  <my-custom-element>... more elements</my-cutom-element>
  <my-custom-element>last</my-cutom-element>
</div>
```

These are all green... I want only the last one to be green.

I have also tried `:host:last-child`, that does nothing and `:host-context(my-custom-element:last-child)` also makes them all green.

Answer (score 1):

Take the pointers from my other answer: [Use CSS selectors like :first-child inside shadow dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237571/use-css-selectors-like-first-child-inside-shadow-dom/61246286#61246286)

> Your elements remain hidden in lightDOM!
> any global style you apply (at any time) will be **reflected** to shadowDOM

```js
customElements.define('my-custom-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super()
      .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
      .innerHTML = `<slot></slot><style>:host { color: red; }</style>`;
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <my-custom-element>first</my-custom-element>
  <my-custom-element>... more elements</my-custom-element>
  <my-custom-element>last</my-custom-element>
</div>

<style>
   div my-custom-element:last-child {
        padding:    .5em;
        background: green;
   }
</style>
```

Notes:

- `super()` returns 'this' (the element itself), so you can chain on it
- attachShadow returns `this.shadowRoot`, so you can chain on it
- the `:host-context` you mention will not be supported by FireFox and Safari
  see: [:host-context not working as expected in Lit-Element web component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532839/host-context-not-working-as-expected-in-lit-element-web-component?noredirect=1#comment108874348_61532839)

---

---

#### Re: comment:

> *This might be the real answer, but this is a bummer, I thought the entire point of the shadow dom was to be self contained, if i have to write some styles in a global stylesheet to then style something in the shadow dom that doesn't seem like a great deal, no wonder people gravitate towards things like react and vue when web standards are so poor.*

Think of it this way. if your `my-custom-element` where `<p>` elements; how would a `<p>` know it is ***inside*** the `last-child`... only by referencing **its parent container**.

> ***no wonder people gravitate towards things like React and Vue when web standards are so poor.***

**All** Frameworks do exactly the same, **they wrap things in containers**
(be it in regular DOM, shadowDOM, virtual DOM (memory)

Better stated: **Frameworks *frame* your content in containers.. always**

The Native W3C standard Custom Element API gives **100% control** to use a container or not.

Yes, that means you have to do some scripting/cooking before you can dine.

You have 100% freedom how you want to cook components.

React adds **48 KB** (GZipped) to your download, not to mention the whole build process, not to mention it will never work in unison with any other framework, not to mention it doesn't even [comply](https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/libraries/react/results/results.html) with the ES standard any more.

An extra Custom Element takes you about 15 minutes and maybe 200 **bytes**

Comment: This might be the real answer, but this is a bummer, I thought the entire point of the shadow dom was to be self contained, if i have to write some styles in a global stylesheet to then style something in the shadow dom that doesn't seem like a great deal, no wonder people gravitate towards things like react and vue when web standards are so poor.

Comment: Im thinking ill just write some javascript that generates inline styles because im not going to include this in a global stylesheet to ship to all pages when 99% of my pages wont even have a custom element on it, and im not going to write a style tag in the HTML document itself after using the custom element. id rather just do everything in one JS file.

Comment: added reply in answer